# How to structure GIT repository and DX to enable continuous deployment?

Tags: salesforcedx

I'm trying to setup our CI/CD environment with a gitlab repository (trunk based dev) and it's not immediately clear (at least to me) how to structure our CD to deploy directly to production.

Specifically, I'm struggling to understand how granular to define packages - and, how does DX know what packages to deploy (without manually telling it to)? For example, if we have 6 packages, and only one is updated, how do we programmatically determine that only that package should be pushed to production? Or do we push the entire trunk?

I have the following goals for our CD model:

1. I would rather not deploy the entire master trunk - and instead only focus on the one package (a subset of master) to deploy (to save deploy time)
2. the build/deploy process being entirely automated (no human in the loop)
3. no hard-coding the package names in the build process, and instead programmatically determining what is updated and deploy those packages

So something like the following:

sfdx force:mdapi:deploy --latest_packages

(As discussed, I'm only assuming this is able to be done versus deploying the entire master everytime code is pushed to production)

Considering the ability to deploy single packages, it seems to me that the DX deploy model is antithetical to trunk based development or am I missing something?

I have read quite a bit of articles and online documentation, but I haven't seen anything that makes it clear as to how this is accomplished so any help you can give to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that comes to mind is to put each of your packages in a separate repository. (Probably other good arguments to do that anyway.) Then your CI (Continuous Integration) tool's "do something when a repository changes" mechanism can deploy just that package with a standard:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy
```

But how well this would work would depend on how coupled your packages are. If they are completely independent, then no gotchas. If they have well-defined dependencies, then you may from time to time have to take care with the ordering of commits. But if they have [circular dependencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) that can easily creep in, then this is not going to work.

(It is possible to have multiple source trees in one SFDX project by using multiple directories instead of the default *force-app/main/default*. I tried that on one project and found it more trouble than it was worth as any org changes always got pulled back into just one of the directories.)